# 500 internet server error error_log:TemplateSyntaxError: Caught ImportError while rendering: No module named friends

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, importerror

Recently I am using django and mod_wsgi on Apache.

I am follow the following steps found in a webpage:

**"My application in / mnt / www /, the name of the called mysite, apache and created in the mysite media directory, and then do the following:"**

create apache_django_wsgi.conf file, as follows:

```
Alias ​​/ site_media / / mnt / www / mysite / media /

<Directory /mnt/www/mysite/media>
Order allow, deny
Options Indexes
Allow from all
IndexOptions FancyIndexing
</ Directory>

Alias ​​/ media / / usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media /

<Directory /usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media>
Order allow, deny
Options Indexes
Allow from all
IndexOptions FancyIndexing  
</ Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias ​​/ / mnt / www / mysite / apache / django.wsgi

<Directory /mnt/www/mysite>
Order deny, allow 
Allow from all
</ Directory>

<Directory /mnt/www/mysite/apache>
Allow from all
</ Directory>
```

create django.wsgi file, as follows:

```
import os, sys

# Calculate the path based on the location of the WSGI script.

apache_configuration = os.path.dirname (__file__)

project = os.path.dirname (apache_configuration)

workspace = os.path.dirname (project)

sys.path.append (workspace)

os.environ ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

os.environ ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/ tmp'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler ()

print>> sys.stderr, sys.path
```

I have followed these step but when I run it under Apache through a browser, I get a 500 Internet Server Error. Then I check the erro_log: it says:"TemplateSyntaxError: Caught ImportError while rendering: No module named friends" (friends is the name of one of my module)

The path of my site is /var/BigPrject/mysite

Comment: Are the spaces in Alias ​​/ site_media / / mnt / www / mysite / media / intended? or should it be: Alias ​​/site_media/ /mnt/www/mysite/media/ ? Same with the other paths in your apache_django_wsgi.conf

Comment: it should be Alias ​​/site_media/ /mnt/www/mysite/media/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything looks good to me, except the project folder is not in the python path.

You can validate it by going to the console and trying to `import friends`.

I am guessing, you can fix this, in you case, by adding the following line to your `wsgi` file:

```
sys.path.append (project)
```

Comment: sorry, i have to correct this. Friends is a application file in mystie. And I can only import friends in the python shell when I　am in mysite directory. when i try typing the code of my wsgi file into the python shell line by line. it doesn't even work for the first line. Error massage is : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name __file__ is not defined

Comment: **% url index %** <--
I guess this is what the error comes from

Comment: I have create a new post so that other people with the same question will be easier to find solution later. :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960132/templatesyntaxerror-at-caught-ioerror-while-rendering-13-permission-denied